# A noun for an effort that is done feverishly but pointlessly?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have seen this word before, but cannot recall.

I can recall the scenario : a soldier used this word to describe his time in the army: They followed the commands and fought feverishly "for glory" but all they did was killing and rampaging. So the soldier called that " the time of ___ in my early life."

Comment: Don't you think that belongs to your search engine, or dictionaries and thesauruses? Either way if 'fighting feverishly "for glory" but all they did was killing and rampaging' is feverish but pointless, isn't that purely a question of philiosophy, not English. Can you not think of a dozen words that might fit your "time of…"?

Comment: There are too many possibilities for a word that could go there (*foolishness*, *pointlessness*, *stupidity*, *inconsequence*, *meaninglessness*, and so on). You need to provide more specific criteria.

Comment: I just love guessing games! Context, please.  Were you in this actual scenario, or like Ronald Reagan are you confusing a movie with reality?

Answer (score -1):

Although many possibilities exist (see the comments for several ending with suffix -ness), both nouns "waste" and "vanity" fit well in the context of your example - a noun for "expending much misdirected time and energy in vain".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vanity

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/waste